# Posting With Spring HATEOAS / Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have two domain objects in my project, `Document` and `Project`.  `Document`s are associated with a single `Project` each.  I'm using Spring-Data-Rest and it's `Repository` abstraction, so I have this:

```
@Entity
public class Project extends AbstractLongIdEntity {

    @Column(length=50,nullable=false)
    private String title;

    @Column(length=200,nullable=true)
    private String description;

...

}


@Entity
public class Document extends AbstractLongIdEntity {

    @Column(length=50,nullable=false)
    private String title = "New Diagram";

    @Column(length=200,nullable=true)
    private String description;

    public Document() {
    }

    public Document(String title, String description, Project project) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.project = project;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Project.class, optional=false)
    private Project project;

...
}
```

When I GET a `Document` over HTTP, I get this back:

```
[DEBUG] TEST - Response: 201 {
  "title" : "My Document",
  "description" : "Some name for a document",
  "dateCreated" : "2018-02-13T06:33:14.397+0000",
  "lastUpdated" : null,
  "internalId" : 1,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/documents/1"
    },
    "document" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/documents/1"
    },
    "currentRevision" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/documents/1/currentRevision"
    },
    "project" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/documents/1/project"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I can't POST the same content back to create the `Document` in the first place.  The best I've found is that I can POST this:

```
{
  "title" : "My Document",
  "description" : "Some name for a document",
  "project" : "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/1",
  "currentRevision" : null,
  "dateCreated" : 1518503594397,
  "lastUpdated" : null
}
```

However, this seems really weird, as:

a) I now have an unnamed, untyped link embedded within the object, and this isn't very HATEAOS (although Spring seems to deserialise it correctly).

b) I now have to create a *separate* class, `DocumentResource` looking like this:

```
public class DocumentResource extends ResourceSupport {

    public String title;
    public String description;
    public String project;

...
}
```

In which, `Project` is a `String`.  Which is a pain as I now essentially have two very similar domain objects.

So the question:  What is the right way to POST new entities in HATEOAS / Spring Data Rest and have them create relationships in the database?

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.10, which seems to bring in Spring-Data-Rest 2.6.10 and Spring-Hateoas 0.23.0.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try posting like this:

```
{
  "title" : "My Document",
  "description" : "Some name for a document",
  "project" : "/projects/1",
  "currentRevision" : null,
  "dateCreated" : 1518503594397,
  "lastUpdated" : null
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, yes, I mention this approach, and why it’s not great in the question.  It works, kinda, but it’s not what I’m after